# Docker eating up space. Won't let go until reoot

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We use docker to run postgresql. It keep eating up space until there is no more space to eat. We need to reboot the machine for it to work again (usage space reduce from 100% to 23%). What could be the cause of this? We are running docker 1.11.2

Comment: Look for what is taking up the space.

Comment: We notice the /var/lib/docker is taking up space which reduced away when reboot.

Comment: Is the data in the container continuously growing? Do you get the space back when you stop, remove and start the container again? Which storage driver are you using?

Comment: We run postgres which use a mounted folder to store all of its data. The storage driver is aufs. I think postgres is emitting a lot of log to stdout/stderr but it doesn't make sense for docker to eating up space due to text written to stdout/stderr? Yes, we do get space back when we use docker compose to rebuild the container.

Comment: It could be an issue with your logs taking up all of the space, if the logs are spammy.  Look at [log-opts](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/) and the `max-size` option for automatically rolling the logs.